# React Native Payment

Tags: react-native, payment

I am building a React Native app that requires Credit Card Payment(visa & Mastercard), What is the best method that I can implement so it will run smoothly both on Android and IOS ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs). 
That should work out for you.

Comment: Strip is MIT license ( Not GNU ) and it doesn't appear free.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out the [Shopify Buy Button](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/js-buy-sdk), it's a fully enabled Javascript SDK.

Answer (score 1):

[Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs) and [Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/) are both easiest solution.

Comment: Stripe can be used in philpines ?

Comment: Strip is MIT license ( Not GNU ) and it doesn't appear free.